# C# & MongoDB.Driver - Why can't I find async methods as the documentation mentions?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asynchronous

I am currently working on a ASP.NET Web/API project and I migrate from SQL to MongoDB.

I currently follow that link:

https://www.codementor.io/pmbanugo/working-with-mongodb-in-net-1-basics-g4frivcvz

However, as I could read in the post above and on internet, there should be `async` methods but for some reason, I have nothing async available.

- .NET 4.6.1
- MongoDB.Bson v2.8.0
- MongoDB.Driver v2.8.0
- MongoDB.Driver.Core v2.8.0

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these two imports to your classes and see if the async extensions become available:

```
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

may i also suggest using [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities/blob/master/README.md) library instead of dealing with the c# driver directly. made my life so much easier.

Comment: Hey :) it worked when I uninstalled everything and just installed mongodb.driver